# What tense would we use when we want to create sentence that interrupt present perfect continuous or overlap with it in some part?

Tags: tense, present-perfect-progressive

I learn that when we use past perfect continuous and we want to describe an interuption or another situation that happens we would use simple past in another sentence. I want to know it's same for present perfect continuous? What tense is the commen way to describe another situation in this cases ?

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure the question works, because present perfect continuous doesn't really get "interrupted." Like, I guess the past-perfect-continuous example is "We had been waiting for hours when he finally arrived." But I wouldn't say "I have been waiting for hours *when* [... something happens?]"

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/138287/andy-bonner
We have been waiting for Nancy for the last two hours, but she still hasn't arrived.

Comment: Perhaps using "while" and the present perfect. An example: "While I have been waiting here, ten people have already asked me when the next train is coming." - although this isn't really an interruption as such, rather things that have happened while waiting. The waiting hasn't stopped yet.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/68154/billy-kerr this was so helpful, can l ask why did you use present perfect and not any other tenses?

Comment: Because *I have been waiting* is still ongoing in this context, it began in the past and is continuing in the present, and the present perfect connects the past to the present.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/68154/billy-kerr but what if the second action would be ongoing too? for example in your previous example, what if people continue to coming to ask her about next train.

Comment: Perhaps "While I have been waiting here, people keep asking me when the train is coming" or "people have been repeatedly asking me"

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/68154/billy-kerr thank you it was so helpful 

Answer (score 2):

You just use past tense.

> I've been practicing the piano recently, but yesterday I took a day off and played tennis, so today I've been practicing extra hard.